# why the dataframe generated using merge operation is not of 3x3 dimension rather than 3x5?

Tags: python, pandas

i follow the instruction http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html, **but is confused when the merge colums is not of the same index**. for example, column 1 in d3 corresponding to column 1 in d4.

```
In [92]: d4
Out[92]:
    0  1
0   9  1
1  11  3
2   1  2

In [93]: d3
Out[93]:
   0  1
0  2  3
1  1  9
2  3  9

In [94]: d3.merge(d4, how='left', left_on=0, right_on=1)
Out[94]:
   0  0_x  1_x  0_y  1_y
0  2    2    3    1    2
1  1    1    9    9    1
2  3    3    9   11    3
```

i think the result should be

```
   0  1 2
0  2  3 1
1  1  9 9
2  3  9 11
```

**Edit 1**:
why the following merge could create an exactly 3x3 DataFrame, while the formmer can create a 3x5 DataFrame?

```
In [164]: d1
Out[164]:
   0   1
0  1  10
1  2   5
2  3   7

In [165]: d2
Out[165]:
   0  1
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  8

In [162]: d1.merge(d2, on=[0])
Out[162]:
   0  1_x  1_y
0  1   10    5
1  2    5    6
2  3    7    8
```

Comment: I don't see your problem here: Your expected result is just a subset of the columns panda's `merge` provides. Merge syntax is `x.merge(y)`.
`0` is the join column and is same as you would expect. Your `1` column is the `1` column of the `d3 (=x)` data frame, so `1_x`, Your `2` column is the `0` column of the `d4 (=y)`data frame, so `0_y`. Pandas can't know that you would like to call it `2`, but it sure knows where this column comes from and names the column accordingly.

Comment: @cel Replied in Edit 1

Comment: Good question. From the merge command in your first example we know that 0, 0_x and 1_y will have the same values. From your second example we know that 0, 0_x and 0_y will have the same values. But this time pandas seems to notice that and does not report 0_x and 0_y. Let's see if someone knows a good explanation for that.

Answer (score 2):

In your first merge you are merging lhs on column '0' and rhs on column '1' but you have no identical values so it has to create two columns with suffixes. The remaining columns have no matches either so you create additional columns.

In the second example you merge on column '0', whereby you do have identical values so it doesn't need to create an additional column, however you still have a clash of column names for '1' and values so it has to create the additional columns with suffixes.

I think your confusion stems from the expectation that because you've specified the columns to merge on that it will then use these columns like an index and match the other columns against these rows, it will not. It will only do this if you set these columns as the index:

```
In [23]:

merged = df1.set_index(keys=[1]).merge(df2.set_index(keys=[0]), left_index=True, right_index=True,how='left')
merged.index.names=['2']
merged.reset_index()
Out[23]:
   2   0  1
0  1   9  9
1  3  11  9
2  2   1  3

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

so I'm setting the index on these columns and setting the `left_index` and `right_index` params to `True`.

However we have to then recover the index as a column, the first issue is that the index name clashes with an existing column name so we rename it.

We can then call `reset_index` to recover the values.

Comment: the behavior of pandas is a bit confusing, then how to create 3x3 dataframe in Example 1?